# Remove "disabled" via JS but button still disabled?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 buttons: the first one is per disabled; the second one enables the first button, thats the plan.
Button 1:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#click').click(function() {
    document.getElementById("submit-disabled").disabled = false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="submit-disabled" name="cusubmit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" disabled />
<input id="click" type="button" value="Enable" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

After click on button 2, "disable" is removed from button 1, but its still disabled...

Does anybody have an idea??

Comment: I made the example runnable, which shows that the code works... voting to close since the issue was something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know why you are using pure JS combined with jquery. I would stick with one (original JS is faster). Also, your code looks ok. I created this FIDDLE and all should work ok:

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/wsqe2hzs/

```
var $click = document.getElementById('click');
var $submit = document.getElementById('submit-disabled');

$click.addEventListener('click', function () {
    $submit.disabled = false;
});
```

There must be something else thats making this happen. Try the code I provided, if it is still giving you problems, provide us with more code so that we can pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to toggle too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly remove the disabled property:

`$("#submit-disabled").removeProp("disabled");`

Comment: Thanks, I am so blind: I had a section: <fieldset id="form-disabled" disabled> around the button 1 ;-)